# Python 3.5 on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy Django using Heroku.

When I type `git push heroku master`

*Traceback*:

[image]
According to this traceback, it seemed to tried `import markdown_deux` in  but no module named 'markdown_deux`.

I check my pip list and this module is Django-markdown-deux and I have installed

So I don't know why caused the error.

Comment: Are you checking pip on your local machine or on heroku? Because if the module isn't on heroku then it's not going to work

Comment: Looks like the package `markdown_deux` is not installed there. Have you read the docs for how to install pip dependencies on Heroku?

Comment: finally i solved by setting 'markdown_deux' to  the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py